# Creating multiple tcp socket handlers from one class in Python

Tags: python, sockets, handler, socketserver, tcpsocket

Is it possible in Python3 to create a TCP Socket handler class that can have multiple unique instances?

I have 2 threaded TCP Socket servers that are providing unique information to the connected client. I am trying to make it so that 'node 1' socket server handler will provide only the data for 'node 1' while 'node 2' socket server handler will provide on the data for 'node 2'.

I have made a custom handler with the variable 'node'.

```
class NodeTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        socketserver.BaseRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)
        self.node = 6
        return
    
    def handle(self):
        logging.debug("Node Socket has been started")
        global stop, temperature, humidity, pressure, voltage
        
        logging.debug("{} connected to Node 0{} Socket".format(self.client_address[0], self.node+1))
        
        while not stop:
            msg = (str(temperature[self.node])+','+str(humidity[self.node])+','+str(pressure[self.node])+','+str(voltage[self.node]))
            self.request.sendall(msg.encode())
            time.sleep(5)
```

I have tried to set the variable 'node' after creating the socket server and defining the handler.

```
node_01_server = socketserver.TCPServer((hostAddr, nodePort[0]), NodeTCPHandler)
node_01_server.RequestHandlerClass.node = 0
node_02_server = socketserver.TCPServer((hostAddr, nodePort[1]), NodeTCPHandler)
node_02_server.RequestHandlerClass.node = 1

node_01_thread = threading.Thread(name='Node 01 Socket',target=node_01_server.serve_forever)
node_02_thread = threading.Thread(name='Node 02 Socket',target=node_02_server.serve_forever)
```

This is close to working, but when I set the 'node_02_server.RequestHandlerClass.node' it over writes the 'node_01_server.RequestHandlerClass.node' node variable as well!

I am obviously missing something but I feel I am close to a solution. This is my first real attempt at using classes and socket servers so if I have made any obvious mistakes please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line `node_01_server.RequestHandlerClass.node = 0` sets class attribute `RequestHandlerClass.node`, not instance attribute which it seems you would like to change. And since there can be only one class attribute `node` of the class `RequestHandlerClass` it is updated on each such line.

Let's consider a couple of ways to separate your handlers:

1. Implement several `NodeTCPHandler` and pass the right one into `TCPServer`

   ```
   class BaseNodeTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
       NODE_TYPE = 6

       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           self.node = self.NODE_TYPE
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   class Node0TCPHandler(BaseNodeTCPHandler):
       NODE_TYPE = 0

   class Node1TCPHandler(BaseNodeTCPHandler):
       NODE_TYPE = 1
   ```

   and now you can pass those `Node0TCPHandler/Node1TCPHandler` into an appropriate server

   ```
   node_01_server = socketserver.TCPServer((hostAddr, nodePort[0]), Node0TCPHandler)
   node_02_server = socketserver.TCPServer((hostAddr, nodePort[1]), Node1TCPHandler)
   ```
2. Implement custom `TCPServer` which can take additional arguments and pass them into the handler's constructor

   ```
   class NodeTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

       def __init__(self, node, *args, **kwargs):
           self.node = node
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   class CustomTCPServer(socketserver.TCPServer):

       def __init__(self, *args, node=6, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           self.node = node

       def finish_request(self, request, client_address):
           """Finish one request by instantiating RequestHandlerClass."""
           self.RequestHandlerClass(self.node, request, client_address, self)
   ```

   and now you can instantiate servers with different `node` values like that:

   ```
   node_01_server = CustomTCPServer((hostAddr, nodePort[0]), NodeTCPHandler, node=0)
   node_02_server = CustomTCPServer((hostAddr, nodePort[1]), NodeTCPHandler, node=1)
   ```

The first approach is better since it requires fixes in a smaller number of classes, especially if more similar updates are coming.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed response, I definitely was missing the fact that I was changing a class attribute and not an instance attribute. I am going to implement the first solution because it doesn't require me to make a custom server class as well. Thanks again